# Database backup not succeeding

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to backup my database but nothing happens when i try to backup, but if i hard-code the path it works.

This method works with hard coded file path.

```
dbBackup.Devices.AddDevice(@"C:\Backup\saveFile.bak", DeviceType.File);
```

But i tried the second, the one i want the user to input the file path but it does not work and the input is exactly the same.

```
dbBackup.Devices.AddDevice(@"'"+ txtPath.Text +"'", DeviceType.File);
```

Comment: Why you add single quotes arounf the text?

Comment: What is the value of txtPath.Text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding quotes similar to how this is done with a direct T-SQL command is not necessary.  The string will be correctly parsed without these.  Given that the text from the hard-coded value and user input is the same as specified in your post, the following will return the same result for both.

```
dbBackup.Devices.AddDevice(txtPath.Text, DeviceType.File);
```